# Private Methods in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I like to keep purely internal methods separate from my classes' public API's, so I have a lot of private categories in my .m files, e.g.

```
@interface Foo (Foo_Private)

-(void)clicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

The problem is that when I use the method dropdown (aka Ctrl-2), the private method declarations all show up first, so when I start typing "clicked" while the dropdown is open, the method declaration gets selected instead of the implementation, so it's basically impossible for me to navigate via keyboard.

This is really annoying. Is there any way around this? I've seen people suggest that you keep your private method declarations in a "Foo_Private.h" but I'd rather not have to create a separate header for every class that uses private methods.

Comment: Is it for an iPhone app or a Mac app? Note that you cannot 'click' on an iPhone. Just so you know :)

Comment: He is talking about XCode, not iPhone vs. Mac development.

Comment: @Radek S, I'm talking about clicking inside Xcode...

Comment: @Bill I know. I was talking about the method name in your example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hold a modifier key down while opening the function dropdown (the particular modifier depends on the version of Xcode, IIRC), it sorts the functions alphabetically instead of in source order. This will allow you to type to jump to the correct method.

On an unrelated note, you can use class extensions instead of categories. They look like a category, except they have nothing between the parens, as in

```
@interface Foo ()
```

The main benefit of this over a category is you can declare (or redeclare, to change readonly->readwrite) properties here that get synthesized inside of the @implementation.

Comment: You're my hero - in Xcode 3.2.x, Ctrl-Option-2 lets me hop right to the implementation method and the class extension tip is helpful too. Thanks!